# PowerShell - User's MemberOf and Owner Status

Tags: powershell, csv

So I wrote a script and I think it's overly-complex, which would be fine if it did what I wanted.  This is in PowerShell v2, by the way.  I'm still trying to get this company to at least use v4.

This script is designed to query the user for a user ID (samAccountName) and display a list of that user's status of membership and ownership for all groups in AD.

```
$Path = Get-ScriptDirectory

$Date = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')

$Domain = Get-ADDomain | select -ExpandProperty NetBIOSName

$Username = Read-Host "Input User ID"

$Filename = "$Path\$Domain" + "_" + $Username + "_Groups_" + $Date + ".csv"

$GetContent1 = "$Path" + "GetContent1.csv"

$GetContent2 = "$Path" + "GetContent2.csv"

$Memberships = "$Path\$Domain" + "_" + $Username + "_Memberships_" + $DATE 
+ ".csv"

$Ownerships = "$Path\$Domain" + "_" + $Username + "_Ownerships_" + $DATE + ".csv"

$LastFile = "$Path\$Domain" + "_" + $Username + "_Group_Status_" + $DATE + ".csv"

$Owner = Get-AdGroup -Filter {ManagedBy -eq $Username} -Properties samAccountName | select -expandproperty samAccountName
$o = get-aduser -filter { CN -eq $Username } -properties DisplayName, memberof
$o.MemberOf.ToString()

Get-ADUser $Username -Properties Memberof | %{$_.memberof} | %{get-adgroup $_ | select name} | Export-Csv $GetContent1 -NoTypeInformation

Get-AdGroup -Filter {ManagedBy -eq $Username} -Properties samAccountName | %{$_.samAccountName} | %{get-adgroup $_ | select name} | Export-Csv $GetContent2 -NoTypeInformation

$o | select DisplayName, samaccountname, @{name="MemberOf";expression={($_.MemberOf | ForEach { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name }) -join "`n"}}, @{N='Groups Owned';Expression={$Owner -join "`n"}}| Out-GridView

import-csv $GetContent1  | select -Property @{name="MemberOf";expression={$($_.name)}}| Export-Csv $Memberships -NoTypeInformation

import-csv $GetContent2  | select -Property @{name="Owns";expression={$($_.name)}}| Export-Csv $Ownerships -NoTypeInformation

$filea = import-csv $Memberships
$fileb = import-csv $Ownerships

for($i=0;$i -lt $filea.count;$i++){
    $filea[$i] | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Owns -Value $fileb[$i].Owns
}

$filea | export-csv $LastFile -NoTypeInformation
```

The Out-GridView section seems to be working fine.  However, when I combine the two CSVs, I'm not getting all the results.

I believe it's because the membership list is shorter than the ownership list, so it looks like it's only accepting the data from the second CSV up to the point where the first CSV data stops (e.g. if the membership field only has 2 lines of data in the column, the ownership field will stop at 2 lines, even if the user ID has ownership of 30 groups).

Can anyone help me find a way to fix this?

Comment: So based on end user input find all the groups that user is a member of and all groups that same user manages?

Comment: Correct, but as you know, I'm a complete hack.  :)
I just want it to drop out a CSV with that information.  I can get two separate CSVs, but when I combine them, it drops anything in column 2 if there is no further information for column 1.

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like? Would be nice to see an example. Right now the easy thing would be one row with 3 columns. username, memberof and owner. The last 2 would be semicolon delimited strings. Show us what you want to see. I am guessing you want a column of memberof and a column of owner and however many rows is the longest one.

Comment: You are correct again, sir.  Just username in the first column, then memberships in the second, and ownerships in the third.  As long as it displays all the information for memberships and ownerships, I don't really care how it looks beyond that.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be easiest if I get-content from $fileb and for-each "," in $fileb I could append a " ," to $filea.  That would even out the columns and maybe solve the issue.  I'm going to see if I can figure it out, but I'd be grateful if anyone who knows how to do that could show me.

Comment: Okay, just because I want to be finished with this idiot problem, I added:  `$Comma = ","` and a line that just says `$Comma | Add-Content $Memberships`.  Now if nobody comes up with an answer I'm just going to have that line run about 200 times because I'm tired of messing with this stupid problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the code about your file naming conventions the following will take the username read from console and build a file where the first column is the just the username, the second column is the group memberships and the third column is the groups that user manages. Since this format is not a true csv we fake it by looping through all the groups and manually setting the first 2 lines.

```
# Set the output file
$file = "C:\temp\test.csv"

#$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Type in a username:"
$groupMemberships = Get-ADUser $Username -Properties Memberof | Select -ExpandProperty memberof | ForEach-Object{Get-ADGroup $_} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$groupsManaged = Get-AdGroup -Filter {ManagedBy -eq $Username} | ForEach-Object{Get-ADGroup $_} | Select -ExpandProperty Name

# Calculate the longest entry. 
$maxEntries = $groupMemberships.count, $groupsManaged.count | Measure-Object -Maximum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Maximum

# Build the output lines and just use Set-Content since we are not using object that Export-CSV would enjoy. 

# Create the header
'"Username","MemberOf","ManagedBy"' | Set-Content $file

# Create the first entry outside the loop since it is special as the only one with username
'"{0}","{1}","{2}"' -f $Username,$groupMemberships[0],$groupsManaged[1] | Add-Content $file

# Arrays are zero based so we adjust the count for that and for skipping the first line.
1..($maxEntries - 1) | ForEach-Object{
    '"","{0}","{1}"' -f $groupMemberships[$_],$groupsManaged[$_] | Add-Content $file
}
```

We take advantage of a feature of PowerShell that if you reference an array element that does not exist a null is returned. So if you have more memberof than managedby it wont fail. The file will be as long as which ever variable contains more entries.

Comment: Dang, Matt. You're really good at this. I ended up doing a `$GroupNumber = get-adgroup -Filter *` and then set `$GroupCount = $GroupNumber.count` then piped `$GroupNumber | ForeEach {$Comma | Add-Content $Memberships}` to make the MemberOf line always contain at least as many commas as there are AD groups. I like yours better. I can't wait to test it. Thanks!

Comment: `$GroupNumber | ForeEach {$Comma | Add-Content $Memberships}` should be `0..$GroupCount | ForeEach {$Comma | Add-Content $Memberships}` in my version, but it adds over 20 thousand blanks.  :P  As soon as I can test yours I'm sure I'll mark it as the answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: I get the following error:  `Cannot index into a null array.
At D:\UserAdminScripts\0_Powershell_Test_Scripts\Get_User_Member_Owner.ps1:36 char:70
+ '"{0}","{1}","{2}"' -f $Username,$groupMemberships[0],$groupsManaged[ <<<< 1] | Add-Content $Filename
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (1:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray` and the only resulting file is the CSV with headers; no data.  Any ideas?